# INPCs not firing for multiple properties from setter of "driving" ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

**My Senario:** I have two ListBoxes bound to two different ObervableCollections--a collection of shapes and a collection of colors user may select from to find part numbers with matching attribute criteria. (More attribute collections exist in my app but I am omitting them for clarity.)

Upon a selection from either of the two attribute value-containing listboxes, I gather the resulting part numbers possessing the selected attribute property in a collection called `ResultingPNsIntersect`. (The collection of resulting part numbers is displayed in the third ListBox.)

**What *should* happen:** after making a selection in either of the two listboxes, the intersection of resulting part numbers possesing that Selected'Attribute' should update so that only relevant part numbers remain. If a shape has been selected, the listbox holding the `ColorsCollection` must update so that only color attributes (in `ColorsCollection`) relevant to PartNumbers that have the `SelectedShape` are displayed in the second listbox.

**My Problem:** After selecting a shape, the `ResultingPNsIntersect ObservableCollection` updates, but the PropertyChanged notification for `ColorsCollection` is never fired, so the second listbox never updates to give the user the updated color attributes to choose from.

I've done this before in other apps without any problems. I see no need to subscribe to `CollectionChanged` since I am not editing property values in ResultingPNsIntersect--I am replacing the collection with new values. Please help me see where my code is failing *and why* so that I can better understand the conditions INPCs require for firing.

**The xaml binding:**

```
<ListBox x:Name="SelectFromAvailableShapesLB" DockPanel.Dock="Top"  
         ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableShapesCollection}" 
         DisplayMemberPath="AttVal" 
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedShape, Mode=TwoWay}"/>


<ListBox x:Name="SelectFromAvailableColorsLB" DockPanel.Dock="Top"  
         ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableColorsCollection}" 
         DisplayMemberPath="AttVal" 
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedColor, Mode=TwoWay}"/>


<ListBox x:Name="PnsResultingFromAttributeSelectionsLB" DockPanel.Dock="Top"  
         ItemsSource="{Binding ResultingPNsIntersect}" 
         DisplayMemberPath="PartNum" 
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPartNum, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

**My ViewModel:**

```
    public ObservableCollection<AttributeValuesLibrary> AvailableShapesCollection
    {
        get
        {
            if (_resultingPNsIntersect != null)
            {
                foreach (PartNumber shape in _resultingPNsIntersect.Where(x => x.ShapeID != null))
                {
                    if (!_availableShapesCollection.Contains(shape.AttributeValuesLibrary_Shape))
                    {
                        this._availableShapesCollection.Add(shape.AttributeValuesLibrary_Shape);
                    }
                }

            }
            return _availableShapesCollection;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_availableShapesCollection != value)
            {
                this._availableShapesCollection = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("AvailableShapesCollection");
            }
        }
    }


    public ObservableCollection<AttributeValuesLibrary> AvailableColorsCollection
    {
        get
        {
            if (_resultingPNsIntersect != null)
            {
                foreach (PartNumber color in _resultingPNsIntersect.Where(x => x.ColorID != null))
                {
                    if (!_availableColorsCollection.Contains(color.AttributeValuesLibrary_Color))
                    {
                        _availableColorsCollection.Add(color.AttributeValuesLibrary_Color);
                    }
                }

            }
            return _availableColorsCollection;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_availableColorsCollection != value)
            {
                _availableColorsCollection = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("AvailableColorsCollection");
            }
        }
    }

    public AttributeValuesLibrary SelectedShape
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedShape;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedShape != value)
            {
                _selectedShape = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedShape");
                RaisePropertyChanged("ResultingPNsIntersect");
            }

        }
    }


    public ObservableCollection<ConnectorPartNumber> ConnAttPNResults
    {
        get
        {
            // If a shape has been selected, we need to navigate to it's related PartNumbers and add those to the intersection
            // contained by ResultingPNsIntersection. 
            if (_selectedShape != null)
            {
                var shapeResults = _context.PartNumbers.Where(x => x.AttributeValuesLibrary_Shape.AttValID == _selectedShape.AttValID);

                if (_resultingPNsIntersect != null)
                {
                    var resultsFromPreviousSelection = _resultingPNsIntersect;
                    _resultingPNsIntersect = new ObservableCollection<PartNumber>(resultsFromPreviousSelection.Intersect(shapeResults));
                }
                else if (_resultingPNsIntersect == null)
                {
                    _resultingPNsIntersect = new ObservableCollection<PartNumber>(shapeResults);
                }
              }
            return _resultingPNsIntersect;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_resultingPNsIntersect != value)
            {
                this._resultingPNsIntersect = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("ResultingPNsIntersect");
                RaisePropertyChanged("AvailableColorsCollection");  <--Not firing!!!!!

            }


        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

::UPDATE:: I can force this to work if I put the `RaisePropertyChanged("AvailableColorsCollection")` in the setter of my `SelectedShape`. But it makes less sense there, of course, because AvailableColorsCollection is dependent upon the `ResultingPNsIntersect` Collection which changes based on a selection in the attribute listboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in general your approach is going to give you issues. Instead of implementing the logic in the getters of your properties, you should consider making your properties much "dumber". I would move this logic out of the properties into a helper method that modifies your available options:

```
private readonly ObservableCollection<AttributeValuesLibrary> _availableShapesCollection =
    new ObservableCollection<AttributeValuesLibrary>();
private readonly ObservableCollection<AttributeValuesLibrary> _availableColorsCollection =
    new ObservableCollection<AttributeValuesLibrary>();

public ObservableCollection<AttributeValuesLibrary> AvailableShapesCollection
{
    get { return _availableShapesCollection; }
}

public ObservableCollection<AttributeValuesLibrary> AvailableColorsCollection
{
    get { return _availableColorsCollection; }
}

public AttributeValuesLibrary SelectedShape
{
    get { return _selectedShape; }
    set
    {
        if (_selectedShape != value)
        {
            _selectedShape = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedShape");
            SelectedShapeChanged();
        }
    }
}

public ObservableCollection<ConnectorPartNumber> ConnAttPNResults
{
    get { return _resultingPNsIntersect; }
    set
    {
        if (_resultingPNsIntersect != value)
        {
            this._resultingPNsIntersect = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ResultingPNsIntersect");
            UpdateAvailableOptions();
        }
    }
}

private void SelectedShapeChanged()
{
    // If a shape has been selected, we need to navigate to it's related 
    // PartNumbers and add those to the intersection contained by ResultingPNsIntersection. 
    if (_selectedShape != null)
    {
        var shapeResults = _context.PartNumbers.Where(x => x.AttributeValuesLibrary_Shape.AttValID == _selectedShape.AttValID);

        if (_resultingPNsIntersect != null)
        {
            var resultsFromPreviousSelection = _resultingPNsIntersect;
            ConnAttPNResults = new ObservableCollection<PartNumber>(resultsFromPreviousSelection.Intersect(shapeResults));
        }
        else
        {
            ConnAttPNResults = new ObservableCollection<PartNumber>(shapeResults);
        }
    }
}

private void UpdateAvailableOptions()
{
    if (_resultingPNsIntersect != null)
    {
        _availableColorsCollection.Clear();
        _availableShapesCollection.Clear();

        foreach (PartNumber color in _resultingPNsIntersect.Where(x => x.ColorID != null).Distinct())
        {
            _availableShapesCollection.Add(color.AttributeValuesLibrary_Color);
        }

        foreach (PartNumber shape in _resultingPNsIntersect.Where(x => x.ShapeID != null).Distinct())
        {
            shapes.Add(shape.AttributeValuesLibrary_Shape);
        }
    }
}
```

If you would rather have settable properties, the `UpdateAvailableOptions` could create new collections and set the `AvailableColorsCollection` & `AvailableShapesCollection` properties to the new instances (but then there is no need for `ObservableCollection`s).

I would even take this a bit further actually. Since you don't want anybody to alter your Available collections, I would make them return `ReadonlyObersvableCollection` instances, and make their return types `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Oops...ok I changed the names so that it would be clearer in example. Everything is correct in my code with the naming, just in my analogy in my question have I made a type-o...I apologize

Comment: Okay, I've updated my answer, because I didn't think your approach is really the one you're going to want to use for this.

Comment: Actually, the Available collections must update. When a user makes a selection in one of the Available collections, it updates the PartNumbers collection that is relevant to the selection, and then updates the OTHER Available collections so that now only the attributes in the intersection are available. I need the ObservableCollections themselves to be recalculated when a Selection is made. I hope that's clear.

Comment: Right. But You want to do the updating of the collections in your ViewModel. You wouldn't, for instance, want the user to add a new color to AvailableColors. That is why I suggest those collections be read-only. As far as other selections are concerned, you would write them much like the `SelectedShape` property (calls `SelectedShapeChanged` which you'd rename). Notice that when the `ConnAttPNResults` property changes, it updates the available items.

Comment: Right, my logic as well. What I don't understand is why I have to Raise the "AvailableColorsCollection" notification in the setter of SelectedShape. Shouldn't this raise when I put it in the setter of ResultingPNIntersect?? That's what the change is actually dependent upon -- not what attribute selection is made, but the fact that the intersection of part numbers has changed. Thank you for your help, @AbeHeiderbrecht

Comment: Well, since you aren't changing the instance of `AvailableColorsCollection`, and it is an `ObservableCollection`, you don't need to raise the property changed notification. WPF will recognize when the collection changes (through the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface that `ObservableCollection` implements). You therefore don't raise a change notification for the property. And part of my reasoning for the architecture change is to avoid raising property change notifications for properties other than the one you are setting. Sometimes you need to, but it is best to avoid it if possible.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35166/discussion-between-spacerach-and-abe-heidebrecht)

Comment: This is fantastic. Thanks so much again. Will be adding an updated version to my question (for anyone else stumbling upon this).